# Skyrim Alftand Weapon

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I cleared Alftand without any quest that required me to enter Alftand. I already read that there are two different quests on this location, and one is concerning a weapon. I would like to know which weapon it is so I don't change it or sell it or use it please.

Comment: do you know which quests?

Comment: No, i just stumbled upon this location, when I searched for this location I found out that there are two quests that refer you here, but didn't say which quests...

Comment: It will most likely vary on your level and maybe a quest that you have equipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know which weapon it is so I don't change it or sell it or use it please.

It is generally not possible to do this.

Skyrim flags important items as "quest items."  These items cannot be dropped, sold, or otherwise removed from your inventory by conventional means (modding and console hacks are an entirely different story).  Generally speaking, quests which involve items fall into three broad categories:

1. The item does not exist until the quest begins.
2. The item is flagged as a quest item even before the quest begins.
3. The whole dungeon is locked until the quest begins.

(1) is common for [radiant quests](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Radiant#Quests), or quests which are procedurally generated (and often repeatable).  (3) is common for [factional](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Factions) quests, particularly those involving the Thieves Guild.  (2) is the interesting case: The item is flagged as a quest item even though the quest is not yet underway!  It turns out that the quest actually is ongoing in this case, it just hasn't appeared in the journal yet.  There are a whole lot of "quests" that never appear in the journal, because quests are a handy construct for setting up scripted events.

The point, however, is that in all three of these cases, it is impossible to "lose" the quest item before the quest has begun.  Note, however, that we left out an important fourth category: bugged quests.  Some quests are bugged in various ways, and it's not inconceivable that a quest might fail to set the "quest item" flag.  In this case, you may be able to use the console to fix the issue by either giving yourself the missing item (`player.additem xxxxx 1` where xxxxx is the item ID and 1 is the number of items you want) or advancing the quest to the appropriate stage (`setstage xxxxx yy` where xxxxx is the quest ID and yy is the stage number).

Answer (score 4):

For all your Skryim questions, first check [The Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com). If you don't, most of your answers are basically just going to be links to the wiki and block quotes, like this one.

The wiki has a [page on Alftand](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Alftand).

The first sentence says this:

> Alftand is an ancient Dwemer ruin located in The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim. The quests "Elder Knowledge" and "Discerning the Transmundane" concurrently unfold here.

**[Elder Knowledge](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Elder_Knowledge)**

> Elder Knowledge is a quest available in The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim. The quest is the twelfth in the main questline of The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim. The quest is particularly long, spanning five different locations, including two Dwemer Ruins. During the quest much of the Elder Scrolls lore is revealed.

No particular weapon is involved in this quest.

**[Discerning the Transmundane](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Discerning_the_Transmundane)**

> Discerning the Transmundane is a quest available in The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim. It serves as the Daedric quest for the prince Hermaeus Mora. It also runs concurrently with the main quest "Elder Knowledge," and is the only other method of accessing Blackreach other than Elder Knowledge.

This quest does not involve a particular weapon either.

**Other Possibilities**

The Alftand page also mentions that it may be used as the random target of the quest [Ancient Technology](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ancient_Technology). This quest can provide an upgrade or ammunition type for the crossbow, so it might be what was being referenced.

Comment: Thanks, this info will really help me on my gaming experience :-)